# how to remove label after animation finished

Tags: python, animation, pyqt, pyqt5

```
def make_frame(self):
    label_name = QLabel(self)
    label_name.setGeometry(20, 630, 40, 30)
    label_name.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(233, 94, 25); ""border : 2px solid black; ")
    label_name.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
    label_name.show()
    return label_name

def animation(self):
    self.label = self.make_frame()
    self.anim = QPropertyAnimation(self.label, b"geometry", parent=self, duration=3000)
    self.anim.setEndValue(QRect(120, 630, 40, 30))
    self.anim.start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is to use the finished signal of the animation to call the deleteLater() method.

```py
def animation(self):
    label = self.make_frame()
    anim = QPropertyAnimation(label, b"geometry", parent=self, duration=3000)
    anim.setEndValue(QRect(120, 630, 40, 30))
    anim.finished.connect(label.deleteLater)
    anim.start()
```

Comment: could you gave me an example , because I tried but it did not work

Comment: sorry I did not see it , it works for me Thank you